# Wear OS redirect issue PKCE

Tags: android, redirect, authorization, wear-os, pkce

In our watch app project, we are using the [PKCE](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/auth-wear#DAG) approach to open a web view on a phone where the user puts login and password, and then using as a redirect url `https://wear.googleapis.com/3p_auth/com.your.package.name?code=xyz` 
however, last month this feature stopped working and now we are stuck in this screen.
[image]

When a user clicks the allow button nothing happens and there is no call back on watches. However, I can see in logcat of an Android device this exception
`Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=com.google.android.wear:/3p_auth/app.html?full_suffix_from_redirect=my.package.wear.dev?code=l77kRQFoTVZv7TdlXy0fC3Q-pkGwlK9HQNlRL9uP4Xxns flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.companion.authentication.AuthenticationRedirectActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{ea1b7ce 21568:com.android.chrome/u0a148} (pid=21568, uid=10148) not exported from uid 10170` 


I am trying to find a way to declare/config this redirect url to get back callback to the watches app.

 Just note, we don't have any app on a phone and we have no control of it. Moreover, this flow used to work and with some recent changes it just stopped.
Please help to find a direct, where I can find a fix here.

Comment: Related ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/313669167